# Bookmarklet to auto-refresh AND find text on page?

Tags: javascript, find, bookmarklet, page-refresh

I am trying to write a bookmarklet to auto refresh a page every timeout period, AND search for some text after each refresh (The purpose is to catch a specific text the minute it appears on the page).

I managed to do auto-refresh like here: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=1a37ccbdde5902fd

And I managed to do periodic search (without refresh) with code like:

```
setTimeout('reload()',1000*timeout);
function reload(){
  setTimeout('reload()',1000*timeout);
  searchText();
  window.location.reload();
}
function searchText() {
  var myRegExp = 'so';
  var t = document.body.innerHTML;
  var matchPos1 = t.search(myRegExp);
  if(matchPos1 != -1)
alert("There was a match at position " + matchPos1); 
  else
alert("no match");
}
```

But I can't get auto-refresh AND search working together.
Anybody?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that your reload bookmarklet is going to refresh the page, wiping out the javascript which was added to the page by the bookmarklet.  Even if you remove the `searchText` call, I expect you will see that the page only reloads once.  The reloading wipes out the `setTimeout` that you had created.

You could probably solve this using the solution in the link you posted that uses a frame.  Since it only reloads the frame and not the overall page, it won't wipe out your javascript.

Comment: Yes, that is my understanding also, but I couldn't combine the two successfully. Once the frame is loaded I can't search it because document.body.innerHTML is the frame and not the original html anymore.

Comment: Right, you'll need to search inside the frame.  Not sure the exact syntax of that.

Answer (score 1):

Solved (well, almost...)

```
javascript:
var myRegExp = prompt("Enter text to watch out for");
timeout=prompt("Set timeout [s]");
current=location.href;
setTimeout('reload()',1000*timeout);

function reload(){
  var found = searchText();
  if (!found) {
    setTimeout('reload()',1000*timeout);
    fr4me='<frameset cols=\'*\'>\n<frame id="frame01" src=\''+current+'\'/>';
    fr4me+='</frameset>';
    with(document){write(fr4me);void(close())};
  }
}

function searchText() {
  var f = document.getElementById("frame01");
  if (f != null && f.contentDocument != null) {
    var t = f.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
    var matchPos = t.search(myRegExp);
    if(matchPos != -1) {
      alert("There was a match at position " + matchPos); 
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```